# Inverted index - How to represent dates?

Tags: date, inverted-index

How do I represent dates in an inverted index? For example, `6/30/16`.

Here's what I understand if a variable is a string:

**Variable:** City

**Values:** San Francisco, Seattle, New York

```
Inverted Index
San Francisco = [1 0 0]
Seattle = [0 1 0]
New York = [0 0 1]
```

How do I do the same for a DATE or DATETIME variable?

Comment: What do the ones and zeroes mean here?

Comment: They are the number of occurrences for unique categorical variable. So SF, Seattle, and New York are all columns at the top. 
If a value has SF, the 1st column is 1 and the others 0.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  You use of `datetime` makes this question smell like SQL/database, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Further information: I have a large dataset of 250+ features. It has numerical data and categorical data. In order to run it through models, I have to convert the categorical data to numerical data. I'm doing that with the inverted index. I think I know how to convert strings to the inverted index format but I am not clear how to do so if the categorical datatype is a datetime.

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere.  It really depends on the model.  Perhaps the most course grain categorization of your dates would be to bucket years or maybe quarters.  Or, you could do months or weeks.

Comment: Oh I see! So you're saying create a bucket at least of years. Starting, say, at year 1950 as 1. 1951 as 2. Etc. And create buckets for month 1...12. Possibly Quarters 1...4. Day of Month 1...30. Some combination of those buckets?

Comment: It totally depends on what your model is designed to be predicting.  If, for example, you were looking for the season to be a predictor, then you could use quarters for all your date time values.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for all the information

Comment: For your next question, try to be more specific.  I have done some data mining in the past, so was able to tease out what you were getting at, but it seems that most others seeing your question did not see it.

Comment: Fair enough, I can do that for the next time. From past experience, too much information dissuades people from reading the post and answering.